# Android seekbar not showing

Tags: android, seekbar, invisible

Folks, I have the following layout: http://dpaste.com/hold/755261/

It has two seekbar widgets. Both are not showing. If I move them to the root linearlayout, they appear, otherwise not. I need them to be inside the first linearlayout. Anyone could help me how to achieve that?

Comment: The code in the link does not appear anymore. Next time, paste it in the question, please.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to put the following in your third LinearLayout:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: Or you can set the android:layout_width to "match_parent"

Answer (score 0):

Change the second LinearLayout height to wrap_content. If the content doesn't fit on the screen, then maybe you have to use a ScrollView.